# Exporting areas of one sheet into pdf. with two pages in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to export two different areas, which display one page each, into an combined pdf. page.
At this time, I only got a code for one page with the programm selecting and exporting a given area of the sheet.

I couldn't work out though, how this could be made with two pages, by selecting two areas to export.

This is my code for the first page:

```
Sub ExportingPage1()

Dim FileName As String
FileName = Sheet1.Range("Z8") & " " & Sheet8.Range("AC11") & ".pdf"
Sheet1.Range("C7:T70").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=DateiName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

How can this be done with two pages, like not only giving it the are ("C7:T70") but also another area for the second page of the file (i.e. "C71:T120")??

I tried using an array function i found while researching about this problem.

It looked like this, but didn't adjust to a given area..

```
Sub ExportingPage2()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String

FolderPath = "the Folderpath"
DateiName = Sheet1.Range("Z10") & " " & Sheet1.Range("AC11") & ".pdf"

MkDir FolderPath

        Sheets(Array("Name of Sheet1", "Name of sheet 2 i copied the data for page 2 into")).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=DateiName, openafterpublish:=True, ignoreprintareas:=False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the PrintArea of the sheet, you can obtain a two-page PDF.

---

Option1:

```
Sub ExportingPage()
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("Z8") & " " & Sheet8.Range("AC11") & ".pdf"
    Sheet1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "C7:T70,C71:T120"
    Sheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sFileName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

---

Option2:

```
Sub ExportingPage1()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim objWK As Workbook
    sFileName = Sheet1.Range("Z8") & " " & Sheet8.Range("AC11") & ".pdf"
    Sheet1.Copy
    Set objWK = ActiveWorkbook
    With objWK
        .Sheets(1).Copy after:=.Sheets(1)
        .Sheets(1).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C7:T70"
        .Sheets(2).PageSetup.PrintArea = "C71:T120"
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFileName , _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Option3:

```
Sub ExportingPage3()
    Dim sFileName As String
    With Sheet1
        sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("Z8") & _
            " " & Sheet8.Range("AC11") & ".pdf"
        .PageSetup.PrintArea = "C7:T120"
        .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Range("C71")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFileName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip,
with this code it uses the given areas but still puts them into one page?

Comment: @MGO I am not sure if it is related with your printer page setup. Please try option 2.